# Is it possible for byte arrays, returned from BufferedStream.Read(), to have different lengths?

Tags: c#, equality, bytebuffer, comparison-operators

We have this old code in our repo:

```
    bool BufferByteCompareFiles(string filePath1, string filePath2)
    {
        int bufferCapacity = 0x400000;
        var firstFile = File.OpenRead(filePath1);
        var secondFile = File.OpenRead(filePath2);

        using var firstStream = new BufferedStream(firstFile);
        using var secondStream = new BufferedStream(secondFile);

        if (firstFile.Length != secondFile.Length)
            return false;

        var firstBuffer = new byte[bufferCapacity];
        var secondBuffer = new byte[bufferCapacity];

        int bytesReadFirst;
        int bytesReadSecond;
        do
        {
            bytesReadFirst = firstStream.Read(firstBuffer, 0, firstBuffer.Length);
            bytesReadSecond = secondStream.Read(secondBuffer, 0, secondBuffer.Length);

            if (bytesReadFirst != bytesReadSecond || !CompareByteArrays(firstBuffer, secondBuffer))
                return false;

        } while (bytesReadFirst > 0 && bytesReadSecond > 0);

        return true;
    }

    static bool CompareByteArrays(byte[] first, byte[] second)
        => first.Length == second.Length && Interop.memcmp(first, second, first.Length) == 0;
```

and the part that I don't understand is why check the byte array lengths in `CompareByteArrays` when already there is an `if` statement checking if `bytesReadFirst != bytesReadSecond` and those ints are the amount of bytes read by `BufferedStream.Read()`.

Am I missing something or can the whole `first.Length == second.Length` be omitted?

Comment: This code seems wrong in the case where the number of bytes read is less than the size of the buffers as it will compare beyond the data that has actually been read.

Comment: Also, if the goal is to check if the two streams are identical, it's quicker to test whether their lengths are identical, first.

Comment: @KlausGütter, sorry, posted entire method, do you still think the issue stands?

Comment: @Yarin_007, posted entire method, there is such a check, yes.

Answer (score 1):

Frankly, that code is simply wrong. These are two different tests:

1. the first tests checks whether the amount *read* in each `Read` call is the same; `Read` doesn't define what it will return - `Read` is given a buffer with an `offset` and `count`, and can return

- 0, for an EOF scenario
- any number between 1 and `count` (inclusive) if *some* data is available (it is *not* required to fill `count` bytes; whatever is convenient is fine)
- or throw an exception

2. the second test checks whether the *arrays are the same size*; this is a very different question

However, because of `1`, the test itself is doomed; we have a huge buffer here (too large, IMO); it would be entirely valid for `firstStream.Read` to return 3 and `secondStream.Read` to return 42, and that would tell you *absolutely nothing* about whether the payloads are the same - you have to keep reading both streams and comparing however many **intersecting bytes** are available in both. The easiest way to do that would be to *fill both buffers each time*, i.e.

```cs
static ReadOnlySpan<byte> ReadAsMuchAsPossible(Stream stream, byte[] buffer)
{
    int read, totalRead = 0;
    while (totalRead < buffer.Length && (read = stream.Read(buffer, totalRead, buffer.Length - totalRead)) > 0)
    {
        totalRead += read;
    }
    return new ReadOnlySpan<byte>(buffer, 0, totalRead);
}

// ... loop over the streams, with, per iteration
Debug.Assert(firstBuffer.Length == secondBuffer.Length);
var firstChunk = ReadAsMuchAsPossible(firstStream, firstBuffer);
var secondChunk = ReadAsMuchAsPossible(secondStream, secondBuffer);
bool chunkSame = firstChunk.SequenceEqual(secondChunk);
```

letting the runtime worry about optimizing the span comparison

Comment: wait... i just now realised `first.Length == second.Length` compares array sizes. So, won't that ALWAYS be true, since both arrays are created with the same size of `bufferCapacity`? How would `Read` returning different numbers not tell me anything? I'm testing whether the files are identical, byte per byte. So if `Read` returns two different numbers, one byte stream is shorter and thus, not equal. Also, calling `Read` already advances the seeker, or whatever it was called, calling it a second time with an offset of 0 will begin reading from where the first call left off.